# Using Aggregate Functions in sql

Tags: sql, aggregates

Hoe can I do following thing without using a VIEW from one Query.

```
!--CREATE THE VIEW

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW BDGTMGR
AS
  SELECT MANAGERID,SUM(BUDGET) AS BDGT FROM 
  N_DEPT GROUP BY MANAGERID ;

!-- THEN GET RESULT FROM THE VIEW

SELECT MANAGERID FROM BDGTMGR WHERE BDGT = (select MAX(BDGT) FROM BDGTMGR);
```

Here N_DEPT is may original Table which has columns named DID, MANAGERID and BUDGET.

I want to get MANAGERID who controls Maximum Budget. A Manager can control more than one Department. DID is the primary key for this table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   MANAGERID,SUM(BDGT) 
from     N_DEPT 
group by MANAGERID 
order by SUM(BDGT) desc limit 1
```

Comment: assuming you are using mysql placed `limit`, if you are using sql server use `top 1` or if you are using oracle use `rownum=1`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT aux.MANAGERID
FROM
  (SELECT MANAGERID,
         SUM(BUDGET) AS BDGT
   FROM N_DEPT
   GROUP BY MANAGERID) aux
INNER JOIN BDGTMGR b ON b.MANAGERID = aux.MANAGERID
WHERE b.BDGT = (select MAX(BDGT) FROM BDGTMGR);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work (modify depending on your flavour of SQL):

```
SELECT TOP 1 MANAGERID FROM N_DEPT GROUP BY MANAGERID ORDER BY SUM(BUDGET) DESC
```

Comment: this will get all managerid's, possibly you need to make a top 1 ;) (or limit)